# Parcel, ClassLoader and Reading Null values

Tags: java, android, parcelable, parcel

I am trying to understand how to read null values from Parcel properly. Let's look my use case:

```
public class MyModel implements Parcelable {
    private Long id;
    private String name;

    public MyModel() {}

    public MyModel(Parcel in) {
        readFromParcel(in);
    }

    @Override public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeValue(id);
        dest.writeValue(name);
    }

    public void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        id = (Long) in.readValue(Long.class.getClassLoader());
        name = (String) in.readValue(String.class.getClassLoader());
    }
}
```

For the sake of this question, let's take an example of field `name` which is of `String` type.

I understand I can use `writeString` instead of `writeValue`, but `writeString` will throw `NullPointerException` if `name` was null.

So now the real issue is, if `name` was null and i attempt to `readValue` and then casting null to `String` will throw an Exception.

What is the best approach to read null values from Parcel in that case? 
Do I need to check for null every time I attempt to read from Parcel? But that will be too much if you have a lot of fields in a model.
Is there a difference between passing `null` or a `ClassLoader` when reading? 
Does a class loader returns an empty/default object if the value is null when reading Parcel?

The error I usually get is this, which happens when it is reading one of the Strings from Parcel:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.company.MyActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@42b82908: Unmarshalling unknown type code 7209045 at offset 1368`

Comment: writeString(null) will work, see how writeValue is implemented: http://androidxref.com/4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/Parcel.java#1182 it just uses writeString with the passed argument

Comment: @pskink I see that writeString calls nativeWriteString, do you know where those are implemented?

Comment: why do you want to know this? its perfectly OK to write null String, try to call writeString(null) and it will work, btw its here: http://androidxref.com/4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/jni/android_os_Parcel.cpp#641

Comment: @pskink I was just curious. Thanks.

Comment: @pskink I have a related question about writing `Long`, not primitive but the object `Long`. if it is null at time of writing, what will it be when I am reading? Because readLong returns `long` not `Long`, so will that `long` be a random value?

Comment: then use: Long l = (Long) parcel.readValue(Long.class.getClassLoader());

Comment: @pskink but if readValue returned null then casting will fail and throw exception, right? Or does ClassLoader prevents that? I guess I don't understand ClassLoader very well.

Comment: i dont understand what you really want

Comment: @pskink Actually just confirmed that writeLong will throw NullPointerException if Long is null.

Comment: then use writeValue if you need null Long

Comment: @pskink Thanks. Sorry about these extended questions. Just trying to understand the Parcel. Appreciate your time.

Comment: What you say here is just **not true**: "writeString will throw NullPointerException if name was null" See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34370801/383414) and [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34370623/383414).

Comment: @SherCoder `writeLong(long)` expects a primitive `long` value, rather than a `Long` object. The npe you get is from Java autoboxing your `null` into a `long` before it gets passed into the method. That is why you can't do that. With a `String` object it is different, since the `writeString(String)` method expects an object reference, not a primitive.

Answer (score 1):

How about supply `ClassLoader` with `MyModel.class. getClassLoader()`?

Comment: An example would help improve this answer, but there's no reason to flag it. If you don't like it, down vote it.

Comment: Clicked "flag" by mistake.

Comment: How would that help? Explanation would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: I wrote a class the same as yours. Then I kept the ```name``` field ```null```, and passed it from ActivityA to ActivityB. When I attempted to get it out of the Intent inside ActivityB, no exception was thrown. Is there any other condition for this kind of exception to occur?

Answer (score 1):

> What is the best approach to read null values from Parcel in that
>   case?

You **can** use the string-specific methods:

- `Parcel.writeString(String)`
- `Parcel.readString()`

**They work perfectly well with `null` values.**

---

For example, assume you have a class with the following fields in it:

```
public class Test implements Parcelable {
    public final int id;
    private final String name;
    public final String description;
    ...
```

You create the `Parcelable` implementation like this (using Android Studio autoparcelable tool):

```
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(id);
    dest.writeString(null); // NOTE the null value here
    dest.writeString(description);
}

protected Test(Parcel in) {
    id = in.readInt();
    name = in.readString();
    description = in.readString();
}
```

Your `Test.name` value will be deserialised as `null` correctly, without requiring any casting to `String`.

Answer (score -1):

I think the best way to do this is to write the length of string `name` before `name`. If `name` is null, just write 0 as its length, and do not write `name`. When reading, if `length` is read and its value is zero, do not read `name` and just set `name` to `null`.

Comment: This is interesting but if I have a lot of String fields in my model, then I will have to do the same for every single one of them.