# Can Nulls be passed to parcel?

Tags: android, parcelable, parcel

Is it possible to write `null` to `Parcel` when parcelling an object, and get `null` back again when unparcelling it again?

Let's assume we have the following code:

```
public class Test implements Parcelable {
    private String string = null;
    public Test(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        source.writeString(string);
    }
}
```

Will I get a `NullPointerException` when reading this value back from the parcel using `Parcel.readString()`?

Or will I get a `null` value out?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, you can pass a `null` to the `Parcel.writeString(String)` method.

When you read it out again with `Parcel.readString()`, you will get a `null` value out.

---

For example, assume you have a class with the following fields in it:

```
public class Test implements Parcelable {
    public final int id;
    private final String name;
    public final String description;
    ...
```

You create the `Parcelable` implementation like this (using Android Studio autoparcelable tool):

```
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(id);
    dest.writeString(null); // NOTE the null value here
    dest.writeString(description);
}

protected Test(Parcel in) {
    id = in.readInt();
    name = in.readString();
    description = in.readString();
}
```

---

When running this code, and passing a `Test` object as a Parcelable extra in an `Intent`, 2 points become apparent:

1. **the code runs perfectly** without any `NullPointerException`
2. the deserialised `Test` object has a value `name == null`

---

You can see similar info in the comments to this related question:

- [Parcel, ClassLoader and Reading Null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26227095/parcel-classloader-and-reading-null-values)

Comment: This is exactly the behaviour I expected! Thank you for the corrections.

Comment: I'm having apparent problems serializing Double values (that can be null) -  when reading from the Parcel with readDouble() i get a double (primitive) back, and that fails, with "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double java.lang.Double.doubleValue()' on a null object reference"

Comment: Yes, `getDouble()` returns a primitive double that would have to have been added with `setDouble()` which also takes a primitive double. I imagine if you try that with a null `Double` object you would run into problems.

Comment: I have a List of custom class right after a string that can be null. If I call writeString() as normal as you show above, I get the nasty unmarshalling unknown type error for the next List during deserialization of Parcelable. If I use empty string if it is null, then it works perfectly.

Comment: @Mehmed you should probably post that as a new question with full details. I recommend linking to this question and answer, explaining the differences in detail so it does not get closed as a duplicate (which would be likely otherwise).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write other data types such as `Integer`, `Double`, `Boolean` with possible null values to a parcel, you can use `Parcel.writeSerializable()`.

When reading these values back from parcel, you have to cast the value returned by `Parcel.readSerializable()` to the correct data type.

```
Double myDouble = null;
dest.writeSerializable(myDouble);  // Write

Double readValue = (Double) dest.readSerializable();   // Read
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case
 (Kotlin)

```
 override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        parcel.writeInt(if (PapperId == null) -1 else PapperId)
        parcel.writeString( if (Nome == null) "" else Nome)
}
```

Comment: Imo using default values must be used only after a case analysis. 
If we'd use your method to store a Integer price, then without value it would default to 0, i can buy it, a lot of it !!
Really, no value is different than default value.